# Include static data files in an NPM package, use them in a portable way

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, commonjs

I want to publish an NPM package that contains a large-ish amount of static data files. There could be 1000 files, containing 1 KB of data each, yielding 1 MB or so of data. It is important that that the environment only load files as they are required by the code (which is determined at runtime).

I want the package to be usable from both server and client, and using any CommonJS implementation.

How can I do this in a user-friendly way?

Although less important, is there a way to structure the code so that a module system is not required? (e.g. so the code and data can be used through HTML tags).

While specific environments have ways to `require` static data files, those are different and environment-dependent. Different environments also have different ways of accessing the files (in a web browser, you'd send a `GET` request, while in a server environment you'd read the file from the file system).

Comment: can't those static data files merged somehow ? you can find common, 1MB of data will not consume too much space or memory wherever are used.

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix Sure they can be merged, but it's important that data not be loaded unnecessarily. 1 MB is a lot on the client-side, especially considering your entire application might have to wait for the data to download in order to function. The problem is not the number of the files, but rather loading them at all.

Comment: You can put the data in json files. You can require It in the nodejs app and fetch It from client when needed.